# React props.children including null values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, redux, frontend

I have a child component, where I am rendering the content passed as children from the Parent component, where some elements are conditional rendered. So when I am trying to access the props.children do a modification I am getting null and false values( which elements are conditional rendered) in props.children. How to remove them.

StackBlitz URL - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2nfdbc?file=src/App.js

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to remove them? What do you plan to do with `children` in the `Card` component? I ask because `children` is a pretty complex prop with lots of variations in what it can contain, so any manipulation of it beyond just putting it on the page (eg, `<div>{children}</div>`) needs to be done pretty carefully.

Comment: It's not really necessary to remove them. What do you gain by doing so?

Comment: Needs to add a icon based on the type of data, so trying to loop through the children in Child Component, but seeing false values and undefined for conditional elements

Comment: React components should usually not interact with the children. What if someone wraps the contents in a Fragment or adds a div somewhere? Pass that stuff down as normal props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like `children.filter((c) => !!c)` but react is usually able to handle false, null and undefined and properly ignore them.